# How can I access the fields of a data type when using `show` instead of the whole show string?

Tags: string, haskell, constructor

I come from imperative programming and I am learning Haskell. I have following data types:

```
newtype Prename = Prename String deriving (Show)
newtype Surname = Surname String deriving (Show)
data Employment = Employed | Unemployed
data Person     = P Prename Surname Employment

jondoe = P (Prename "John") (Surname "Doe") Employed
```

How can I access the Strings of `Prename` and `Surname` without the constructors. Currently I get the following output:

```
show jondoe
"P (Prename\"John\") (Surname\"Doe\") (Employed)"
```

but I want it to be

```
show jondoe
"John Doe"
```

I am getting very frustrated because it seems like such a simple thing to, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One way is to write a function that writes the name to the terminal as follows:

```hs
writeName :: Person -> IO ()
writeName (P (Prename p) (Surname s) _) = putStrLn (p ++ " " ++ s)
```

```
λ> writeName jondoe 
John Doe
```

Another way is a function that returns the concatenated full name as a string:

```hs
getFullname :: Person -> String
getFullname (P (Prename p) (Surname s) _) = p ++ " " ++ s
```

```
getFullname :: Person -> String
getFullname (P (Prename p) (Surname s) _) = p ++ " " ++ s
```

A third way is to implement an instance of `Show` for `Person` as follows:

```hs
instance Show Person where
  show (P (Prename p) (Surname s) _) = p ++ " " ++ s
```

```
λ> show jondoe 
"John Doe"
```

But to be honest, I'm not sure if implementing a `Show` instance in this way is a good idea because you loose the `Employment` information. Having a custom function that explicitly says what it does appears the better way to me.

Comment: Oh god thank you I was so close my code was looking like this:
```getFullname :: Person -> String```

```getFullname (P p s _) = p ++ " " ++ s```

but I didnt notice that I am only acessing the constructors again with this pattern, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

`show` is *not* for getting pretty output. It is specifically supposed to produce *valid Haskell code*. Now, `"John Doe"` certainly is syntactically valid, but it doesn't have the right type.

That said, I personally find it perfectly ok to base a `Show` instance on custom smart constructors, which would make it more readable. For example, you could have

```
employee :: Prename -> Surname -> Person
employee pn sn = P pn sn Employed

nonworker :: Prename -> Surname -> Person
nonworker pn sn = P pn sn Unemployed
```

Furthermore, you may ask yourself whether `Prename` and `Surname` really need to be `newtypes`. If you simply make them

```
type Prename = String
type Surname = String
```

then they can be directly printed as... well, strings. Now you could write a `Show` instance

```
instance Show Person where
  showsPrec p (P pn sn Employed)
     = showParen (p>9)
        $ ("employee "++)
        . showsPrec 11 pn
        . showsPrec 11 sn
  showsPrec p (P pn sn Unemployed)
     = ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailded answer :) My type structure is actually a lot more complex, else your suggestion makes a lot of sense but I only listed the ones that were relevant for my question.